# when hovered over element A then element B should be visible using scss alone?

Tags: html, css, sass

```
<element class="a">
  some content
</element>
<element class="a c">
   <element class="b d">
   <element class="b">
   some content
</element>
```

if hovered over element `class="a"` then `class="b d"` should be visible. if hovered over `class="a c"` then `class="b"` should be visible. is it possible to do it only with scss and how to do it?

Comment: we need more context and more CSS, if you are supposed to show the "b d" and "b" elements then how can you hover the "a c"? this one will also be hidden since it has no content inside

Comment: "a c" have other element along with "b d" and "b" have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `:not()` selector combined with `~`

```css
.a:not(.c):hover ~ * .b.d {
   color:red;
   font-weight:bold;
}

.a.c:hover .b:not(.d) {
   color:blue;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  some content
</div>
<div class="a c">
   <span class="b d">BD</span>
   <span class="b">B</span>
   some content
</div>
```